# WPF ListBoxes - change background of one ListBox based on selected items of another ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a WPF window with two ListBoxes. The items for both are added at run time from the view model and the items for ListBox2 (SelectionMode="Multiple") are dependent on ListBox1(SelectionMode="Single") selected item.

Now, I want to update the background of the selected item for ListBox1 whenever the user selects/deselects a item in ListBox2. The background of selectedItem of ListBox1 should update if the selected item count of ListBox2 > 0.

Also, I want the background to remain regardless of the item being selected, i.e. Suppose I am on Obj 1 in ListBox1 and I select some items in ListBox2, now even if I select Obj 3 in ListBox1 the background of Obj1 should not change. I already have a hash set to store all the selected items of ListBox2 in the code behind to which the items are added/removed on selection changed event of ListBox2.

Is it possible to do this from the code behind or using the style triggers ?

Here is the code to make things a bit more clear

```
<Border Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" SelectionMode="Single"
        SelectionChanged="ListBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="ObjBorder" Height="45">
                        <Grid x:Name="lstItemGrid" Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="45">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding LB1Name}" />
                            </Border>

                            <Path Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CheckMark" Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}">
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible, ElementName=CheckMark}" Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="lstItemGrid" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Border>

<Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox2" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" SelectionMode="Multiple"   SelectionChanged="ListBox2_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="ObjBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="45">
                        <Grid x:Name="lstItemGrid" Background="Transparent">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="45">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding LB2Name}" />
                            </Border>

                            <Path Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CheckMark" Style="{StaticResource CheckStyle}"></Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="lstItemGrid" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CheckMark" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: I prefer using ValueConverters for tasks like this, but your approach should work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674233/valueconverter-for-background-color and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533546/use-of-boolean-to-color-converter-in-xaml

Comment: I can't really use a converter because this is a static window and there is no way to notify the UI of the changes in the HashSet (static) which I am using to store the selected items of ListBox2.

Comment: Maybe maybe not. You can pass parameters to your converter